# Divergence as trace of Levi-Civita connection

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

*In "Problems and Solution in Mathematics" by Ta-Tsien, 2nd Edition, exercice 3314, question b*

**Exercise question**

For a vector field $X$ define the divergence of $X$, $\text{div}(X)$ as the trace of the operator $Y \rightarrow D_Y X$ where $D$ is the Levi-Civita connection. Find the expression for the divergence of $X$ in a local coordinate system $(x^1,...,x^n)$.

**Exercise answer**

Denote:

\begin{equation}
X = \sum_i X^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}
\end{equation}

Then, by the definition of divergence, we have:

\begin{equation}
\text{div}(X) = \sum_{k,l} \left<D_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}} X, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^l} \right> g^{kl}
=
\sum_i \left(\frac{\partial X^i}{\partial x^i} + \sum_k \Gamma^i_{ki}X^k \right)
\end{equation}

**My question**

I see $Y \rightarrow D_Y X$ as a "differential" operator in which for example the derivatives of the components $X^i$ and $Y^i$ of the vectors fields will appear. On the contrary, a tensor is a "local" operator which only permits algebraic operations between those components. My question thus is:

What is the coordinate expression of the tensor which trace is the divergence of $X$ ?

Comment: It sounds like you think this trace is supposed to be a number, instead of a function (a "scalar field")?

Comment: I understand that the trace is a scalar field. What I do not understand is what is the tensor field from which the trace is computed at each point.

Comment: That is, I do not understand what is the tensorial expression of the operator $Y \rightarrow D_Y X$.

Comment: $Y$ is a vector field, and $D_Y X$ is a vector field; therefore at any point on the manifold the map $Y \to D_Y X$ could be described by, for example, a matrix. No derivatives of $Y$ will appear in this expression; only those of $X$ (which is fine, because the trace you need only requires linearity in $Y$, not $X$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each $Y$, $X \mapsto \nabla_Y X$ is a differential operator. But for each $X$, $Y \mapsto \nabla_Y X$ is a tensor, i.e., commutes with multiplication by functions (this is part of the definition of a connection).

We can compute the "matrix" for $Y \mapsto \nabla_Y X$ with respect to a coordinate basis $\partial_1, \dots, \partial_n$ (where $\partial_j := \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j})$:
$$ \partial_j \mapsto \nabla_{\partial_j} (X^a \partial_a) = ((\partial_j X^i) + X^a \Gamma_{ja}^i ) \partial_i.$$
So the $ij$th entry of this matrix is $(\partial_j X^i) + X^a \Gamma_{ja}^i$. Said another way, the tensor in question is the $(1,1)$-tensor
$$ ((\partial_j X^i) + X^a \Gamma_{ja}^i) \, \partial_i \otimes dx^j.$$
The trace of this tensor is the divergence.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on the differential vs algebraic operators. Isn't the tensor a $(n,n)$-tensor ?

Comment: @vkubicki - Under the usual convention, this is called a $(1,1)$ tensor because it is a section of $T^\ast M \otimes TM$, i.e., it eats one vector and spits out one vector. (A $(p,q)$ tensor is a section of $(T^\ast M)^{\otimes p} \otimes (TM)^{\otimes q}$, i.e., it eats $p$ vectors and spits out $q$ vectors.) Now, this (and any) $(1,1)$ tensor may be written as an $n \times n$ matrix with respect to a coordinate basis (where $n$ is the dimension of the base manifold); is that what you're thinking of?

Comment: Precisely ! Thank you !

Comment: Correction to my comment above (I accidentally reversed the roles of $p$ and $q$): the usual convention is that a $(p,q)$ tensor is a section of $(TM)^{\otimes p} \otimes (T^\ast M)^{\otimes q}$, i.e., it eats $q$ vectors and spits out $p$ vectors.